# ¿Por qué no se muestra el mapa de Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, google-api

Espero me puedan ayudar he puesto la libreria de javascript de google maps, no me marca ningun error cuando lo ejecuto, pero no me muestra nada, se supone que me deberia mostrar un mapa, ya he visto un poco la documentacion pero no puedo hacer que aparesca, aqui pongo una captura de mi pagina no muestra nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    });
}
</script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBSm8z4EyxJx90791A-iCmoNLQFY-7F9k&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que agregarle el estilo por defecto del mapa:

```
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Te dejo el ejemplo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMjEaz